# Android Studio window rendering/refreshing by clicking on other window on MAC OS

Tags: macos, android-studio

I don't know what kind of keyboard combination I clicked with my MAC OS on Android Studio 1.5.1, but every time I click away to another window (e.g. safari), the complete android studio window is refreshing. The same if I am going back to click on android studio, the complete windows is refreshing as well. It is really annoying, and I don't know how to get rid off it.